# How to get domain name from URL and redirect to respective folder using rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In my application when the url hit like

http://monohar.opens.com

it should redirect to

http://xx.xxx.xx/folder/manohar

Using htaccess rewrite rule , here domain 'monohar' will be dynamic domain name , could be changed to any thing dynamically but url always ends with  'opens.co'

Please suggest me how to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess or Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.opens\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://xx.xx.xx/folder/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

`%1` is back-reference of substring before first DOT in `HTTP_HOST` variable.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, %1 that will trim first domain ex abc.opens.co . If i have something like abc.gear.opens.co , how to write dynamic rule that time ?